# qml access to kde's kwallet

Tags: javascript, widget, qml, kde-plasma

I'm writing a kde plasmoid using qml. It's a widget, displaying mobile usage for one of largets mobile priveders in our country, using the api provided by the operater. In order to get the data one must do a request using phone number + password and I'd like to use kwallet to store "accounts" in some kwallet's folder for this widget.
The question is, how do I use kwallet in qml/javascript based widget, if it is even possible? I can't find any info on the web. I found this plasmoid using kwallet: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/gmail-plasmoid?content=101229
but this one is written in python and is importing some python kde libs, so I can't really use that. Any suggestions or even links to some usefull api would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kwallet can be accessed using qdbus on the command-line. And apparently there is a way to make command-line calls in Javascript plasmoids using the extension `LaunchApp`, like this:

```
Button {
    onButtonClick: plasmoid.runCommand("qdbus",
        ["<add-missing-parameters-here>"]);
}
```

For the extension to work, you need to add this line to your desktop file:

```
X-Plasma-RequiredExtensions=LaunchApp
```

The exact command-line calls go something like this:

1. Make a call to open the wallet

   ```
   qdbus org.kde.kwalletd /modules/kwalletd org.kde.KWallet.open <wallet name> 0 "<your application name>"
   ```
2. Use the returned ID to acess a password

   ```
   qdbus org.kde.kwalletd /modules/kwalletd readPasswordList <wallet-id> kmail "<entry name>" "<your application name>"
   ```

I haven't tried any of this, but theoretically it could work.

Links:

- Example using runCommand: http://server.ericsbinaryworld.com/blog/2012/06/06/developing-my-first-plasmoid-the-qml-code/
- LaunchApp documentation: http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/JavaScript/API-LaunchApp
- Wallet access using the command-line: http://learnonthejob.blogspot.de/2009/11/accessing-kde-wallet-from-cmdline.html

Comment: Thank you, I found some code later that also uses runCommand, but didn't try it as I decided I'll probably write dataengine in python and then use it from qml. But now I'm gonna try this one aswell:)